# How can I solve the error: expat: key "991F6E3F0765CF6295888586139B09DA5BF0D338" is unknown

Tags: linux, docker, archlinux

I want to make a work env by Dockerfile From ArchLinux

docker build -t xiaoduoge/workenv .

```
RUN yes | pacman --sync --refresh
RUN yes | pacman --sync --needed archlinux-keyring
RUN yes | pacman-key --init
RUN yes | pacman -Syyu
```

but have the following error

:: Import PGP key 139B09DA5BF0D338, "David Runge dvzrv@archlinux.org"? [Y/n] y
checking package integrity...
error: expat: key "991F6E3F0765CF6295888586139B09DA5BF0D338" is unknown
:: Import PGP key 991F6E3F0765CF6295888586139B09DA5BF0D338? [Y/n] y
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/expat-2.5.0-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/pambase-20221020-1-any.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/libcap-2.66-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/gnupg-2.2.40-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
:: File /var/cache/pacman/pkg/shadow-4.11.1-3-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst is corrupted (invalid or corrupted package (PGP signature)).
Do you want to delete it? [Y/n] y
error: failed to commit transaction (invalid or corrupted package)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
The command '/bin/sh -c yes | pacman -Syyu' returned a non-zero code: 1

so what should I do to solve the problems?

Answer (score 1):

You have to manually sync the package database and upgrade the archlinux-keyring package before your system upgrade:

```
pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring && pacman -Su
```

This command is not considered a partial upgrade since it syncs the package database and upgrades the keyring package first.

Source and further details in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Pacman/Package_signing#Upgrade_system_regularly).

Comment: thank you, I used your answer but it didn't work, maybe this question is only specific to my environment, but I've found an answer that adapts to my environment.

Comment: @xiaozhu I didn't take the time to add the dockerfile elements but the principal is the same. Just a couple things, afaik you should aim to have fewer RUN commands so a two commands with the AND in the middle is preferable to commands on separate lines. On a separate topic, I have never had to initialise or populate pacman-key - are you sure that is a necessary? Lastly, don't use pacman -Syyu - use the command as above - details are in the arch wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I use these commands and solve my problems:

```
RUN yes | pacman-key --init

RUN yes | sudo pacman -Sy archlinux-keyring

RUN yes | sudo pacman-key --populate archlinux

RUN yes | sudo pacman -Syyu
```